# What is the correct way to transfer database in mojoportal?

Tags: c#, mysql, mojoportal

I have exported the database from the server and imported it on my local pc. I have changed the connection string in my **user.config** file. The database is the same. But after that when I visit any page in my mojoportal project, it shows me an error saying:

> Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).*

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Or how it can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have changed connection string on right place ( Inside portal web.config). There are two connection string one for Authentication and another one is for your application. 
Please check that and if it wont work then get the path of error from Stack trace that will tell you which method is throwing an error after that you need to debug that. (Seems like uniqueidentier field is not properly defined/manged)